# "Silently" invoke helper application using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Can Javascript cause browsers generally (and Chrome for Mac in particular) to invoke an external [helper application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helper_application) for a URI **without** opening a new tab/window, or navigating away from the current page?

The context is that I am developing an extension for Chrome that occasionally needs to invoke particular actions outside of the browser.  Using the rather [neat trick described here](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/linktrigger/), the extension only need open particular URIs to invoke suitable AppleScript.

However, how should one open such URIs from a script running in an extension's [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html)?  I don't think `XMLHttpRequest` will help, as Chrome won't (shouldn't?) attempt to use an external helper application for XHR; nor does it appear that setting `window.location.href` has any effect on such a background page (it is not a problem if the background page is unloaded).

My current solution is to open a new window, but it's unnecessary and rather distracting for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised I can do this with an `<iframe/>` in the background page.  Très simple!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options here:

1. You could write an NPAPI plugin.
2. You can use a WebSocket client in the browser, and run a local server on your desktop. That way you establish a tunnel to your local machine to do pretty much anything you want there.

I did this for relaying global media key presses to control web-based music players and [wrote it up](http://smus.com/chrome-media-keys-revisited). Source [here](https://github.com/borismus/keysocket).

Comment: Thanks Boris.  I realised I can achieve what I need with an `<iframe/>` (posted as a separate answer).  I've previously looked into NPAPI but it seems overkill for my needs; similarly, don't much like the overhead of having a service running to listen for very occasional connections - but it's definitely an interesting approach.